# Prevent line break in System.Windows.Forms.Button

Tags: .net, winforms

is there any way to prevent the WindowsForm button control from performing a line break when the string in its .Text property is too long?

Maybe using SendMessage via PInvoke?!

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: So what do you want to happen instead? :)

Comment: So that the text overflows off of the button? Do you want the string that is too long *centered* on the button, or just to run off the edge? Or so that the button is automatically sized to fit the length of the text? Can you provide us some more information?

Comment: I simply want the text to end when there's no more space left (well, there should be the same margin on the right as it is on the left). Thing is that with a dynamically populated Button control with a text property like "123 - thisissomeverylongstring" all I get to see is "123 - ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button's AutoEllipsis property to True.  This also automatically enables a tooltip so that the user can see the entire button's Text value when she hovers the mouse over the button.

Comment: Damn, that's it. Next time I'm definitely not gonna rule out object members simply on a hunch ;-)